# HDFC iOS SDK crashing to integrate in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode7, payment

**HDFC SDK ( written in Objective - C) Integration in SWIFT**

I am integrating HDFC iOS SDK in Swift . Since HDFC SDK only available in Objective C to i created BRIDGING HEADER to integrate in Swift .

HDFC SDK is created using XIB and my project in storyboard so i embed my storyboard in NavigationController and configurred all mandatory parameter to open PaymentView but it is crashing while opening the Payment Screen.

Here is Crash :

> Unknown class CreditCardCell in Interface Builder file.  ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   makePaymentButton.'

*NOTE - I found there is a custom cell is designed in SDK (.xib and .h ) files are there i tried to reconnect (then remove it ) but nothing works .

Any Help is kindly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
           **HDFC SDK WORKING FINE IN SWIFT**
```

After Spending entire night , i figure out the exact issue :

To Make objective C SDK work in SWIFT :

MOST IMPORTANT PART IS :

> **Build Setting - Linking - Other Linker Flag - (-ObjC)**

Finally Solved .

Comment: you neeed to talk to HDFC development team for this